# Votação revertida - tag PrimaveraBSS

Tags: suporte

Hoje quando acedi ao SO reparei que tive uma reversão de **-492**, e achei algo estranho porque não me tenho apercebido de votações constantes ou sequenciais nas minhas respostas.

Enquanto tentava perceber o que poderia ter causado a reversão pude confirmar que todos os votos que me foram retirados diziam respeito a uma *tag* específica, nomeadamente [primaverabss](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/primaverabss).

Logo de seguida contactei outros membros ativos nessa *tag* que me disseram exatamente o mesmo, ou seja, que tiveram também reversões de votos, em alguns casos acima dos **-500** de reputação.

Alguns deles enviaram-me *prints* da reversão:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Decidimos colocar uma questão aqui no Meta não por causa da reversão em si, mas para explicar o porquê de existirem votações "cruzadas" entre os utilizadores que mais intervêm nesta *tag* em específico, tentando, de certa forma, que, por um lado nos seja devolvida a reputação e por outro, mais importante ainda, tentando evitar que isso continue a acontecer no futuro!

---

A *tag* [primaverabss](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/primaverabss) foi criada para permitir à comunidade técnica de colaboradores, parceiros e clientes da empresa [Primavera BSS](https://pt.primaverabss.com/pt/) (*link* para consultarem mais informação) possam trocar ideias/impressões e tirar dúvidas técnicas, mesmo entre colaboradores da própria empresa, sobre, principalmente, a área de extensibilidade que o ERP disponibiliza.

Desta forma estamos a tentar centralizar as questões num único ponto, onde também outros utilizadores não associados à empresa possam dar o seu contributo e ajudar de forma mais rápida a resolver problemas programáticos.

A ideia será ter uma comunidade auto-suficiente onde, num plano ideal, os clientes e parceiros que utilizam o ERP se possam ajudar mutuamente, sem necessidade sequer do auxílio da empresa em si.

---

Dado ser uma comunidade ainda pequena, com poucos utilizadores, existe a necessidade dos colaboradores da própria empresa, visto serem aqueles com mais conhecimento das ferramentas e linguagem, responderem com mais regularidade às questões, dando origem a votações "cruzadas" entre eles, o que não significa que estaremos com isso a tentar defraudar o sistema, mas sim apenas a votar em questões respondidas corretamente, com conhecimento de causa e válidas para quem as tiver e procurar uma solução.

---

Tendo em conta que o **StackOverflow** é suposto promover isso mesmo, a entreajuda, e dando a conhecer todo este cenário, questionamos se será lógico manter a reversão e se de futuro este tipo de ação se irá manter com este critério, porque nesse caso seremos quase "obrigados" a não votar nas questões de um colega nessa *tag*, mesmo tratando-se de uma resposta válida e nos possa ter ajudado a nós ou a qualquer outra pessoa da comunidade.

Apenas gostaríamos de perceber, caso a reversão se mantenha, como poderemos proceder no futuro para que tal não volte a acontecer, visto que colocamos esforço e dedicação nas respostas a esta *tag* assim como em qualquer outra.

Desde já agradeço, em nome da comunidade, a vossa atenção.

Comment: '*existirem votações "cruzadas"*', talvez este seja o motivo das reversões, como detalhado em [Por que tenho uma alteração de reputação na minha página de reputação que diz “votos a favor/contrários em série revertidos"?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/serial-voting-reversed) onde diz que "votos envolvidos serão invalidados como parte de um processo automatizado". Talvez esse tipo de interação mútua constante indicaria que seria melhor utilizar o Enterprise para tal, pois provavelmente o sistema continuará julgando como manipulação de votos.

Comment: Certo, compreendo essa automatização, mas imaginemos que apenas 20 utilizadores costumam colocar questões e/ou respostas na *tag*, é normal que apenas esses (e poucos mais) votem nesses tópicos, certo? Se assim for iremos continuar a ter reversões enormes se continuarmos a votar nos tópicos dessa *tag* :(

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Esse foi um caso bastante particular, que vai além da automatização do sistema.

O sistema mostrou aos moderadores, por meio de ferramenta automatizada, que havia um padrão suspeito de votação envolvendo diversas contas. A equipe de moderação investigou o caso e constatou que eram muitas contas envolvidas, muitos votos, e por um longo período de tempo. Como nossas ferramentas de moderação também são limitadas, consideramos o caso inconclusivo, e delegamos o assunto à Stack Overflow (empresa).

A equipe de Comunidades da SO avaliou o caso e concluiu tratar-se, provavelmente, de um grupo de colegas de trabalho, como de fato é o caso, conforme você mesmo diz. Porém, optaram por invalidar uma parte dos votos mesmo assim. Como diz [a página de ajuda sobre votos em série](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/serial-voting-reversed):

> Não importa o motivo, este tipo de comportamento de votação direcionada sistemática não é considerado normal e não será permitido pelo sistema.

Nem pelo sistema, nem pelas instâncias de supervisão humana acima dele. Portanto, a recomendação que fica é que evitem ao máximo a votação cruzada em postagens de colegas. Eu entendo o uso que fazem da ferramenta e reconheço a contribuição de vocês ao site como um todo, porém é preciso se adaptar ao sistema e suas regras.

Comment: Concordo a 100% com que diz, e compreendo o porquê da reversão de votos, mas acredito que um *heads up* a informar que iríamos sofrer a reversão **caso** se continuasse com essa votação "cruzada" teria sido uma forma mais correta de proceder, ao invés de fazê-lo diretamente sem pré-aviso. Mas essa é a minha opinião, respeitando, como é óbvio, a do **SO** de ter feito a reversão. Posto isto, a reversão irá manter-se, correto?

Comment: Acredito que sim, irá manter-se, até porque reverter a reversão deve ser tecnicamente custoso. Enfim, aceito a crítica. Eu pessoalmente não esperava que a SO fosse invalidar tantos votos sem nos consultar antes. Pensei que nos dariam informações adicionais sobre os cruzamentos e que decidiríamos juntos, como já foi feito em outros casos. Mas, sim, poderíamos ter enviado mensagens de moderação a alguns de vocês pedindo esclarecimentos.

Comment: Ok, compreendo a posição. Iremos proceder com mais cuidado no futuro. Infelizmente, outros utilizadores, não colaboradores da empresa e que se centram quase exclusivamente nesta *tag* em específico, irão quase de certeza sofrer reversões (se já não sofreram) com regularidade.

Comment: Não necessariamente. Os critérios do sistema para reversão automática de votos são um pouco... misteriosos.

Comment: Percebido :)! Obrigado pelo esclarecimento e atenção @bfavaretto.