# Pedido de criação da tag benner para assuntos relacionados ao framework

Tags: debate

Olá, faço parte da equipe de tecnologia da Benner Sistemas. Temos um framework que é útilizado por todos os nossos clientes, revendas e desenvolvedores em todo o Brasil. Estamos abrindo nosso framework no github e gostariamos de utilizar o stackoverflow para apoiar a comunidade e responder dúvidas sobre o nosso framework também. Será que é possível criar uma tag benner?

Github
https://github.com/benner-sistemas

Blog da Tecnologia Benner
https://dev.benner.com.br

Comment: Na verdade, só usuários com mais de 300 de reputação podem criar tags.

Comment: As tags começam a surgir conforme surgem dúvidas relacionadas as mesmas. Mas como o @LINQ disse, somente usuários com +300 pts de reputação podem criar as devidas. Creio que usar o SOpt para uma comunidade fechada (ou bem específica) não é o ideal, uma vez o SOpt é público e o ideal é abranger um padrão de cenários que qualquer um pode enfrentar, e não somente à um público específico (ainda mais de uma empresa/tecnologia específica).

Comment: Acho que não é o momento, pois a tag deve ser consequência do conteúdo, e não o inverso. Seja lá sobre qual assunto for, antes de mais nada precisamos de conteúdo de qualidade que não dependa de links externos e que trate de problemas conceituais ou práticos de programação. Se precisa por tag específica de um produto de nicho, provavelmente o conteúdo nem se encaixa no escopo (o site não pode servir como mera extensão da documentação de qualquer produto que seja, muito menos substituto desta) - Faço este comentário de maneira abrangente, não só tratando do produto em questão aqui.

Comment: Não sei se é bem o que procura, mas se for para um grupo restrito a rede lançou este produto: https://stackoverflow.com/enterprise .

Comment: Caro Leandro, para mim as tags tem que ser ***naturais***, tem que ter propósito de facilitar a busca e apresentar brevemente algo se isto for útil, se o foco for apresentar um projeto com alguma intenção de marketing não vai funcionar. Eu mesmo criei um framework, a tag apareceu naturalmente devido a dois usuários que se interessaram fora do site nele, e depois vieram com perguntas aqui, eu evito ao máximo fazer "jabá" dele, porque realmente isto provavelmente iria contra as regras. A Stack Overflow, como foi dito já, é uma empresa, até destacava tags antigamente (ou ainda o faz) no **SOen**

Comment: @Leandro no chat estávamos discutindo se o ERP da Benner é escrito em Delphi ou C#, ou outra coisa, pode nos dizer? Só curiosidade mesmo :)

Comment: Claro @Maniero, já faz algum tempo que escolhemos .net. Em 2001 tivemos que escolher entre java e .net, e a escolha foi .net pois interoperava melhor com o nosso legado em delphi. Mas hoje a regra de negócio e a aplicação web é toda escrita em c#.

Comment: A evolução continuou e hoje estamos rodando toda a nossa arquitetura em containers, inclusive o legado em delphi quando existe. Veja a última liberação da tecnologia Benner: https://dev.benner.com.br/tecnologia/190/

Comment: A Benner não é mais uma empresa só de ERP, temos hoje sistemas: Jurídico, Saúde, Turismo, Logística, RH e várias verticais sobre esses sistemas. O que é bem interessante é que todos eles rodam sobre a mesma plataforma. Veja esse vídeo da criação de um sistema de reserva de carros na nossa plataforma web: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7xcGVHHFjFM . Essa plataforma está disponível para que todos os nosso clientes desenvolvam sobre ela.

Comment: Gostaria ainda de listar alguns dos nossos clientes: 
Petrobrás,
McDonalds,
Havan,
Itaipu,
CEEE,
JBS,
HSBC,
Santander,
Citibank,
Banco Original,
TIM,
Telefônica,
Marista,
Postal Saúde (Correios),
Cassi (Banco do Brasil),
DHL,
Patrus,
Águia Branca,
FIESC/SESI,
PRODESP,
PROCON,
INATEL,
Unilever,
Banco Volkswagen,
Huawei,
Banco da China.

Comment: E sobre irmos para o stackoverflow decidimos esperar mais um pouco como vcs nos sugeriram. Vamos abrir toda a nossa documentação que hoje está privada em uma wiki http://wiki.benner.com.br/ e acabamos reativando uma ferramenta de perguntas e respostas que já usávamos https://desenv.benner.com.br/accessviolation/.

Comment: Vídeo institucional do Grupo Benner, dá uma ideia da empresa:  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ji7nTOZWA6I

Answer (score 9):

A criação poderia ser feita, não tem restrições para isto, porém vejo um problema.

Forma colocadas perguntas que chamamos de *farming*, ou seja, só para gerar conteúdo, sem ser uma pergunta real. Isto não costuma ser muito bem visto. Não é proibido, mas depende muito de qualidade. E geralmente é mais adequado quando a resposta pode atingir muitas pessoas, o que não é o caso de um *framework* muito específico e que pelo que vi nem é tão completo, útil e bem trabalhado (só uma opinião superficial).

Essas perguntas precisa se atentar para ser muito bem feita e deixar margem para qualquer pessoa com conhecimento responder. O grande problema é que sendo uma pergunta artificial a pessoa não consegue dar detalhe e geralmente só ela mesma consegue responder. Este tipo de pergunta não é permitida, não porque é de uma *tag*, mas porque ela não é clara, ou é ampla ou até é um pedido para fazer tudo para ela.

Temos aqui uma experiência com um ERP português chamado Primavera. Não está indo bem (inclusive a própria equipe deles parece que abandonou o barco e deixa o problema pra comunidade). As pessoas que o usam não entendem o Stack Overflow que tem uma cultura, não se importam em aprender porque aquilo não faz parte da sua real necessidade e elas sempre criam perguntas ruins, fazendo a experiência delas e dos outros como algo desagradável.

O fato de ter uma caso ruim não impede que outro tente, mas será que vale a pena?

Outro ponto é que o SO não gosta muito de *spam*, e usado de forma inadequada pode ser considerado assim, sabemos que as empresas estão percebendo que ter participação em redes de terceiros é algo importante, mas precisa gerar conteúdo de qualidade que ajude pessoas e não servir como instrumento de marketing. Para divulgação a empresa tem como vender publicidade e para algo mais nichado existe o Stack Overflow Teams para ser adquirido.

Tem alguns sinais vermelhos ligados nessa tentativa. Não estou dizendo que não pode fazer, mas estou dando a opinião que não começou bem (acho que foi outro usuário que iniciou a tentativa, mas deve estar ligado porque um moderador sugeriu perguntar no meta), não sei como outras pessoas pensam. Queria ponderar essas coisas antes de alguém tomar uma decisão.

O Stack Overflow tem sido criticado pela cultura que tem, mas é essa cultura que fez ele se tornar relevante. E o mais importante é que reclamar não vai adiantar nada, a pessoa tem que oferecer alternativas, de uma forma ou de outra. Em geral as pessoas só querem que a cultura dos outros mude pra ficar bom para a cultura do que ela deseja. Isto não faz sentido e não leva a lugar algum.

Acho que este tipo de tentativa pode ser um choque de cultura. Eu venho da cultura do desenvolvimento de ERP, mas sempre fui um desenvolvedor muito mais do que isto e vejo que geralmente as pessoas não são assim, os desenvolvedores de ERP tem uma cultura muito diferente e pode haver um choque. Será que as pessoas usarão mesmo o site? Elas vão se preocupar com as regras daqui? Ou será que elas ficarão bravas porque ela faz do jeito que bem entende e pra ela os outros é que estão errados em fechar coisas ruins dela?

Eu até gostaria que desse certo, mas tenho dúvidas. Pensem nisso antes de uma decisão definitiva. O debate está aberto, acho necessário um processo para acontecer de forma que seja produtivo para todo mundo, pelas experiências anteriores, e já foram algumas outras (algumas voltaram atrás e continuaram com seu processo fora do SOpt), tem que ser feito com cuidado.

Comment: O uso de uma tag específica para uma comunidade faz com que exista um padrão para **votos** nessa comunidade, ainda mais quando a mesma tag é repetida nestes cenários. Isso aconteceu neste [caso](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/7682/vota%c3%a7%c3%a3o-revertida-tag-primaverabss), e o sistema entendeu esse "padrão" como suspeito pela comunidade que usava a tag, e então, reverteu todos os votos (e logo sua reputação).

Comment: Me corrija se estiver errado, mas logo complementando minha ideia dada no comentário à pergunta, a reputação vinda duma comunidade/tecnologia específica faz com que dê para entender que você está "farmando" reputação por um grupo centralizado, que quase é "separado da comunidade SOpt", e logo, o sistema entende isso como spam. Não é?

Comment: O problema ali foi outro, nada tinha a ver com *tag*. Esse problema é outro e eu não me preocuparia tanto porque se houver uma inflação de votos o sistema detecta e providência serão tomadas, independente de *tag*, sempre aprece umas pessoas que se julgam mais espertas, mas em algum momento, mesmo que demore um pouco elas caem.

Comment: Maniero quero agradecer pela resposta e principalmente pela sinceridade, de modo algum queremos gerar spam no stackoverflow ou mesmo não seguirmos as regras dessa plataforma que é tão importante no Brasil e no mundo. A ideia surgiu pois somos uma empresa nacional e temos uma plataforma que é utilizada por vários clientes, revendas e começamos abrir os nosso fontes. Hoje temos uma equipe dedicada a cuidar da plataforma Benner de desenvolvimento e já é rotina respondermos perguntas sobre a plataforma e também sobre as tecnologias que a plataforma utiliza.

Comment: Gostaríamos muito de participar ativamente do stackoverflow Brasil e criar a cultura em nossos desenvolvedores de se envolverem na comunidade. Hoje respondemos várias perguntas que são sobre tecnologias conhecidas no mercado, mas essas respostas ficam apenas no nosso sistema interno. Dente essas tecnologias poderia destacar: asp.net, vuejs, bootstrap, docker, delphi, vba. O sentimento que estamos vindo é de colaboração e compartilhamento de conhecimento. E antes de entrarmos queremos debater o assunto para ver se faz sentido e se está alinhado com o propósito do stackoverlhow.

Comment: @LeandroSalvattiPiscke algumas coisas que podem ajudar vocês: https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7325/101. Veja a participação deste usuário, no começo ele era ativo e contribuía com O SOpt mais que apenas responder as questões do ERP deles, agora nem do ERP ele e outros profissionais desta empresa tem ligado pra isso e fica um monte de pergunta zumbi. Um problema que temos visto é que as pessoas que costumam ser usuários delas tem outras preocupações, não estão acostumadas com comunidade, não ligam pra regras.

Comment: Quando elas acionam um suporte eles estão pagando e podem fazer do jeito que querem, quando estão em comunidade elas precisam seguir o estabelecido pela comunidade, a pessoa tem que entender bem que elas está fazendo algo para todos e não para ela. Este é um erro comum que algumas pessoas cometem quando participam aqui e depois ela se frustra porque ela espera que as pessoas estejam aqui de graça para satisfazer as necessidades dela. No começo o pessoal do Primavera até tentar salvar as perguntas mal feitas dos usuários deles, depois pararam porque é meio que enxugar gelo.

Comment: Note que no site de vocês já viram problemas com relação a esta cultura. Perceba que pode ser frustrante pra todo mundo. Por isso indiquei a possibilidade de usarem um ferramenta igual ao SO mas que vocês podem ter as regras que quiserem. Um dos problemas é as pessoas fazerem perguntas que não são de programação. Outro elas não serem muito claras no que querem, mais seria só pedir para mostrar pra ela como faz algo sem ter um problema específico. Pode ser ruim se alguém postar uma resposta apenas *linkando* para a documentação de vocês.

Comment: Enfim, eu poderia ficar aqui fazendo um livro de possíveis problemas porque já tivemos outras experiências ruins de grupos que até eram mais de comunidade e não deu certo. Eu acho que seria interessante o seu grupo começar participar do site, começar ler tudo o que todo mundo não lê, ir vendo a cultura, is aprendendo, sempre com mente aberta, participar dos debates quando for pertinente, contribuir, mostrar que estão sérios nisto que estão mergulhando aqui, e aí começar trazer no momento certo is usuários de forma orgânica.

Comment: Talvez esperando um pouco mais colocando coisas *open source*, disponibilizando mais documentação. O jeito que começaram eu acho que foi atropelado, mas tudo bem sempre pode-se aprender e começar de novo. EU sou um cara de ERP e me interessa tudo isso, quero até poder contribuir de alguma forma, quero saber mais sobre esse uso do C#, me lembro que a Benner usava outra coisa, nem sei quando mudou, se teve mais mudanças, até antes de uma virada que teve na empresa talvez antes de você estar lá. Eu não mando nada aqui, só estou colocando algumas coisas pra refletirem, pra comunidade avaliar.