# É permitido usar perguntas e respostas para divulgar minha plataforma?

Tags: debate, perguntas, perguntas-fechadas

Olá. Minha empresa criou uma ferramenta de desenvolvimento de software.

Existe programação dentro da ferramenta, mas também existem muitos assistentes e operações que precisam ser feitas com o programa instalado. Mesmo criando o passo-a-passo para simular o problema, seria necessário ter uma licença do produto para instalar e fazer o teste.

Gostaria de saber se é permitido e como deveriam ser feitas as perguntas sobre essa tipo de ferramenta aqui no StackOverflow.

Tentei criar uma pergunta com resposta, com uma boa quantidade de informações (mais do que suficiente para quem conhece a ferramenta), mas ela foi fechada e bloqueada.

Comment: Como um usuário comum do site eu acredito que a inserção de uma ferramenta  ou plataforma de desenvolvimento em nosso escopo deva ocorrer de maneira natural, conforme os usuários demandam resposta de acordo com uso dessa ferramenta e a penetração da mesma dentro da comunidade nacional(ou internacional) de programadores. Não é algo que deva ser forçado, normalmente isso mal visto. Outra coisa que deve se ter em conta é fato que nosso escopo de atuação são as linguagens e frameworks independente de ferramentas de desenvolvimento.

Comment: Eu entendo a situação, mas no meu caso, criei a pergunta de forma "forçada" apenas para conseguir criar a tag.

Comment: Daniel: O que, ou quem, vai criar a tag é demanda e não o contrário.

Comment: Relacionado (um caso parecido): https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7918/112052

Comment: Obrigado @hkotsubo, esse caso me fez entender a preocupação de vocês em "ficarem com o pé atrás" quanto a ferramentas proprietárias.

Comment: Problemas gerados pela inserção artificial de uma tag em nosso escopo: [https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=+primaverabss](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=+primaverabss)

Comment: Caso sua intensão seja documentar as coisas existe o StackOverflow for Teams, vc pode ver mais aqui https://stackoverflow.com/teams

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sua pergunta foi corretamente sinalizada como spam por alguns usuários e removida (spam velado, o que piora a situação).

Sua conta não foi removida (é o procedimento normal nesses casos) pelo fato de você ter feito outras contribuições antes. Assumimos boa fé em relação a estas postagens anteriores (muito comum o pessoal que vem tentar fazer divulgação "preparar o terreno" antes). Diria que seu caso foi até uma exceção (o fato da conta prevalecer), visto a quantidade de outras iniciativas particulares que tentam fazer o mesmo com frequência (as pessoas não notam pelo fato delas "morrerem no ninho").

O caso da empresa citada em alguns comentários foi bem diferente, eles conversaram sobre o assunto e foi combinada uma experiência nesse sentido. Que, por sinal, não deu certo.

Se em algum momento alguém tiver uma dúvida de programação de fato que por acaso envolva sua plataforma, e não for colocada artificialmente no texto, talvez até passe, mas dada a situação gerada, acho extremamente importante evitar. Note isto como uma mera observação, não passa nem perto de sugestão.

### Resumo:

Aqui definitivamente não é o lugar para divulgar plataformas e produtos (exceto nas propagandas pagas separadas do conteúdo, pelo canal apropriado).

Ainda: nos sites internacionais, há tags patrocinadas (Android, por exemplo). Você pode contactar o comercial do site para saber se isto é possível no SOpt.

Comment: Existiu uma outra tentativa onde conversaram com a comunidade antes e ficou estabelecido que eles não iriam usar e criaram uma solução própria. Isso ajuda muito a mostrar boa intenção. È bom deixar claro que isso é regra da rede, nem é algo que a comunidade definiu. Especialmente é válido quando o único objetivo é divulgar um software, para isto existe a publicidade (que eu não sei se estão vendendo para a versão em português). Talvez, e é um enorme talvez que alguém muito ativo tivesse um pouco de condescendência, até porque a pessoa faria mais bem feito, aconteceria naturalmente.

Comment: Certamente forçar perguntas e respostas para divulgar não é adequado. Se aparecerem isso de forma real é algo para se pensar, a experiência anterior mostra que não dá certo também, mesmo outras ferramentas de nicho não dá certo. Uma das premissas da nossa platafroma é ter especialistas naquilo para responder de forma independente. Se só tiver os produtores do software fica complicado, inclusive a edição da *tag* mostra que a motivação é marketeira e não técnica.

Comment: @Maniero inclusive pelo fato de muitos aqui dos realmente engajados na área terem seus próprios produtos, muitas vezes superiores aos de diversas tentativas de divulgação já ocorridas, e que nem por isso usam o site para divulgação.

Comment: Entendi o problema pessoal, obrigado pela boa vontade em me explicar a situação. Só gostaria de deixar claro que embora tenha passado essa impressão, minha intenção não era "Marketeira". Tive a ideia de usar o SOpt pois é uma ferramenta que todo o programador gosta de usar, e acabei interpretando mal os interesses da comunidade.

Comment: E peço desculpas por qualquer transtorno que possa ter gerado para a comunidade.

Answer (score 8):

A pergunta deverá ser feito de forma independente da plataforma. Se é possível rodar C#, então a pergunta será sobre C# e será igual independente de onde será executado. Se a dúvida for de JS a mesma coisa. Basicamente a dúvida será de programação, então não tem nem porque citar a plataforma. "Eu preciso calcular 1+2 usando um lápis", o lápis é uma informação fundamental no problema? Não, então é ruído e deve ser evitado. "Eu preciso calcular 1+2", isso é um problema mínimo, suficiente e verificável que funcionará se você usar um lápis, uma caneta, pedras, fazer a conta mental ou seja lá como preferir. Isso agrega conhecimento, não segrega. O mesmo será com a plataforma. Se a dúvida for realmente da plataforma, não se encaixa no escopo e deveria ser feito no fórum da própria ferramenta.

Inclusive eu vi a edição da descrição da tag que criou e eu a recusei marcando-a como plágio por cópia exata da descrição do site sem citação. Lembre-se que auto-plágio existe, é crime e será evitado aqui na comunidade. Fora isso, a descrição nem descrevia nada, era mais marketing que qualquer outra coisa.

Sobre tentar utilizar o Stack Overflow como plataforma de suporte técnico para os problemas da vossa ferramenta, eu já diria para desistir. Já tivemos experiências anteriores que foram péssimas e apenas afetaram negativamente a qualidade da comunidade (ainda o fazem) e dado isso foi decidido pela própria comunidade a não aceitar esse tipo de pergunta. Pode pesquisar aqui mesmo no Meta pelas discussões da tag do Primareva.

Stack Overflow nasceu para ser um repositório de conhecimento sobre programação, se quiser e conseguir fazer isso de forma independente a um produto próprio e licenciado, será muito bem-vindo aqui, mas se quer apenas dar suporte técnico aos clientes, sugiro criar uma plataforma própria. O Stack Overflow Team surgiu a partir dessa demanda, se te interessar.

Comment: Obrigado pelos esclarecimentos. Acho que entendi o que você quis dizer. Mas como é uma ferramenta para programação, achei que se encaixava no perfil da comunidade. Como por exemplo, uma dúvida sobre Crystal Reports, não vai ser somente sobre o Comando SQL da fonte de dados ou o Script executado nas fórmulas. Por vezes, a dúvida seria de configuração, e a reposta seria uma serie de passos a serem executados dentro da IDE da SAP. Este foi apenas um exemplo que me veio a mente, mas acho que devem existir outras situações. Sobre a descrição da Tag, eu realmente Copiei e colei o texto. Vou editá-la

Comment: Se a dúvida é de configuração, o lugar para se responder seria no FAQ ou fórum da tecnologia. Não é só porque o programa pode ser usado para programação que tudo nele é sobre programação, entende?

Comment: Entendi. Obrigado pela explicação.