# Precisamos da tag primaverabss e jasminsoftware?

Tags: debate, tags, escopo-do-site

Há algum tempo essas *tags* forma criadas e passaram receber perguntas de um ERP de Portugal. Aparentemente sobre programação.

Já [foi discutido antes e houve um teste](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7325/101). Mais recentemente [a empresa questionou o fechamento de algumas perguntas](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7981/101). Inclusive houve [problemas na votação](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7682/101). Não estamos falando mais de um possível problema, já sabemos se tem e qual é o problema.

Se olharmos as perguntas quase todas são mal feitas, em geral por pessoas que mal são programadoras, que não estão interessadas em fazerem parte da comunidade do SOpt e aprender como ele funciona e boa parte das respostas é algo como "foi corrigido o bug na versão tal", e é comum que nem seja uma resposta da equipe do produto como pode ser visto em [Ao gravar documento não atualiza último número da série](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/415362/101). É comum que só a equipe do produto consiga responder e é comum eles não responderem ou demorar muito. Muitos casos nem é sobre programação. Não interessa para uma comunidade de programadores e pelo meu entendimento só é usado para suporte.

Este entendimento é só meu ou outras pessoas acham o mesmo? Perguntas deste tipo podem continuar sendo feitas ou é só ruído que não agrega de fato algo para o SOpt?

Comment: Preciso de ações positivas ou negativas além de votos na pergunta para que a comunidade tome uma decisão.

Comment: Sinceramente, as perguntas boas dessa tag não precisam da tag para serem respondidas. As que precisam da tag normalmente são as que nada tem a ver com programação.

Comment: Boa observação.

Comment: Acho a tag desnecessária para a comunidade, talvez seja necessária para a empresa mas aí é outra história. Me parece que usaram o SOPt como uma alternativa grátis para plataforma de suporte ao invés de criarem ou pagarem por uma plataforma própria.

Comment: Não sei utilizar o [Data Explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/pt/query/38106/tag-statistics), há alguma maneira de visualizar estatísticas específicas para cada tag? (Além das perguntas e visualizações) E eu vejo algumas perguntas da tag `primaverabss` e concordo com o Jorge B.

Comment: Eu evito as tags *primaverabss* e *jasminesoftware* pois em geral as perguntas são sobre incompatibilidade entre a documentação e o framework,  esse tipo de questão deve ser encaminhado diretamente ao fabricante.

Comment: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/415881/101 não fazemos conversão de código a la carte.

Comment: O que acham desta? https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/414047/101

Comment: Mais uma para a coleção: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/416017/consulta-e-cria%c3%a7%c3%a3o-de-modos-de-pagamento-via-webapi

Comment: @danieltakeshi estava de bobeira e fiz uma [query](https://data.stackexchange.com/pt/query/1126066/infos-sobre-tags-jasminsoftware-e-primaverabss), não sei se está 100% certa

Comment: @Barbetta não conta as deletadas, né?

Comment: @Maniero não, estava vendo isso agra

Comment: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/416455/101 parece um caso de erro de programação e não do software deles, certo? Ou seja, pra que essa *tag*?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Infelizmente, no meu ver, foi uma experiência que não deu certo.

Agradeço ao pessoal da softhouse por ter acreditado no produto e tentado trazer um publico novo pro site, mas da forma como ficou entendo que está frustrante para ambos os lados.

A cultura do site é bem específica e clara quanto ao seu objetivo, que não é ser um fórum nem um helpdesk, e sim um repositório de conhecimento em forma de pergunta e respostas. Respostas estas que sirvam para outras pessoas com o mesmo problema, e por isso as postagens tem que ser o mais canônicas e específicas (em relação ao problema) e ao mesmo tempo generalistas (em relação às soluções) para que resolva aquele mesmo problema em cenários variados.

Quanto à tag, acredito que com o devido cuidado, temos a necessidade de dissociar as postagens boas, se houver, e eliminar toda a parte helpdesk. Muito provavelmente, como dito nos comentários, provavelmente o que sobrar nem precisará da tag (e se precisar, será o momento em podemos aferir que convém manter).

UPDATE: Só para não deixar o pessoal que chegou atrasado na conversa sem um feedback, no fim de outubro de 2019 começamos o *phase-out* da tag, com remoção progressiva e tratamento criterioso caso a caso. Os comentários, argumentos e votos da comunidade podem ser acompanhados nos comentários e demais respostas ao post.

Comment: As boas postagens não precisam da *tag* mesmo e podem sobreviver, as que depende da *tag* não são boas e deveriam "morrer".

Comment: @Maniero penso que é caso até de remoção gradativa dos posts, alem do fechamento

Comment: Vamos iniciar o *phase out* então? Só está piorando. Eles nem sequer se preocuparam depois que postamos isto aqui.

Comment: Eu acho que precisa ver se algumas perguntas podem sobreviver sem a *tag*, e retirá-la, quando acabar isso o que estiver com a *tag* deve ser apagada de uma vez.

Answer (score 6):

Só para avisar que a decisão parece tomada e se ninguém começar fazer antes espero ainda este mês começar remover as perguntas desta *tag* (manterão as perguntas que podem sobreviver sem ela) e ao fim a *tag* não existirá mais. Nos últimos meses tem piorado a qualidade da perguntas desta *tag* e quase todas nem sequer eram sobre programação, então só está gerando ruído sem gerar valor algum. Não está bom nem para as pessoas responsáveis por este software quem não estão respondendo nada.

Fazendo uma verificação no conteúdo deu para perceber também que muitas perguntas estão fora dos padrões da comunidade e já deveriam estar negativadas, fechadas ou removidas por causa disto. E em alguns casos não ocorreu porque tem positivos e parecem vir da equipe do software. Mesmo que não seja intencional fazer isso para fraudar o sistema acaba criando uma distorção dando valor para postagens ruins. Em função de não ter intenção de fraudar não cabe punição mas a distorção não pode ocorrer, isto é mais um motivo para indicar que este tipo de *tag* não funciona. Existe um grupo de pessoas interessadas na *tag*. È verdade que isto ocorre outras (por exemplo a pessoa gosta de Python e vota em coisas ruins dessa *tag*) mas não na mesma proporção.

Comment: Esse meu comentário foge do escopo da tag em questão, mas está dentro dentro do escopo de qualidade de pergunta. Eu estava pensando em formas de melhorar a qualidade das perguntas ativas nos site principal e antes de iniciar a pesquisa para criar um debate aqui no meta a respeito eu preciso saber se é possível modificar a quantidade de votos necessários de usuários comunitários para fechar e reabrir uma pergunta?

Comment: @AugustoVasques se eu entendi bem a questão, na prática não é, a comunidade não tem essa liberdade. Na verdade temos bem pouca, e mesmo sem dizer que está tirando autoridade da comunidade a SE pode ir minando o que a comunidade quer e fazer acontecer o que eles querem, o que mais faz pensar se estou no lugar certo.

Comment: Agora fiquei triste, a SE não fornece para as comunidades autonomia suficiente para gerir sua peculiaridades, mas vou pensar em outras formas de contribuir. Quanto essas tags `primaverabss` e `jasminsoftware` tem algo que eu possa ajudar nesse processo de remoção?

Comment: @AugustoVasques se você achar que consegue avaliar bem o conteúdo deles pra sugerir remoção (ou fechamento antes) já seria uma boa. Em alguns caso sonde você percebe que tem ali uma pergunta de programação, independente de ser dessas *tags*, e que possuem qualidade pra manter no site aí seria só retirar as *tags* para que no final do processo fique zero delas as *tags* deixem de existir. Mas pode deixar pra trás se achar que não entende bem do assunto.

Comment: @AugustoVasques segura um pouco porque agora resolveram falar alguma coisa, e também eu vi que alguns casos tirar a *tag* pode até complicar mais, porque a pergunta só faz sentido com a *tag*, sem ela na verdade a remoção deveria ser o caminho. As que deveriam sobrar é só as que não dependam de nada do ERP deles, que seja geral que qualquer um pode responder.

Comment: Me avisa a hora que chegar-mos a um consenso de se devemos ou não remover a [tag].

Comment: @AugustoVasques sobrou algumas pra você ver :D

Comment: Sobrou sim... dá para [contar nos dedos](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/primaverabss).

Answer (score 4):

- Em 11/10/19 foi levantada a questão de pertinência ou não das tags [primaverabss](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/primaverabss) e [jasminsoftware](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jasminsoftware) em nosso escopo.
- A decisão de remoção das tags [primaverabss](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/primaverabss) e [jasminsoftware](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jasminsoftware) foi tomada 12/10/19.
- Foi manifestada apenas uma contrariedade a decisão, sem nenhum apoio, em 11/12/19.

A comunidade continua contrária a manutenção das tags em nosso escopo e não dá sinal que irá reverter esse quadro. Portanto a remoção das tags [primaverabss](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/primaverabss) e [jasminsoftware](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jasminsoftware) continua.

Answer (score -3):

Depois de ontem ter levantado novamente este tema colocando outra questão no debate por indicação do Woss venho aqui defender a continuidade da tag apresentado alguns dados que possam ajudar a que a comunidade decida da melhor forma.

Assim a minha proposta enquanto programador por dentro do tema é:

> Remover a TAG JasminSoftware e passar o conteudo atual para a Tag
>   PrimaveraBss.

Acções emediatas para melhor conteudos

> Sinalizar para remoção de conteudo todas as  que não cumprirem os citerios do SO. Temos feito isso desde a ultima conversa aqui.

Problemas que se assumem

> Falta de cultura de muitos programadores na utilização do SO e  por arrasto a tag sofre.

A comunidade de programadores PRIMAVERA existe, claro que muito deste contudo apenas faz sentido dentro da TAG, sem elas as questões ficam soltas e sem sentido.

Disponibilizamos conteudos para que programadores possam desenvolver com a nossa FW e tecnologia:

[Site DeveloperNetwork](https://developers.primaverabss.com/)

[Repositórios Git](https://github.com/PrimaverabssDeveloper)

[Extensões Marketplace Visualstudio](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/search?term=primaverabss&target=VS&category=All%20categories&vsVersion=&sortBy=Relevance)

Em conclusão, este tipo publico é restrito quando comparado com outras tag, está a começar a fazer o seu caminho na comunidade, mas necessita da nossa ajuda, pois todos eles são progamdores C#, VB.NET, ASP, SQL e podem ajudar em outras tag, mas a cultura tem de ser criada, a sobre tudo tem de ser ajudados nos primeiros passos. 
Peço a comunidade para rever a sua posição.

Exemplos de questões que só com  tag fazem sentido:

- [Assembley resolver não é chamado numa console application](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/389399/assembley-resolver-n%C3%A3o-%C3%A9-chamado-numa-console-application)
- [Qual o método para obter a rastreabilidade de cópia de linhas](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/387769/qual-o-m%C3%A9todo-para-obter-a-rastreabilidade-de-c%C3%B3pia-de-linhas-via-motores-da-apl)
- [Erro 8169: Conversion failed when converting....](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/385820/erro-8169-conversion-failed-when-converting-from-a-character-string-to-uniqueid)
- [V9 - Icons da Ribbon não aparecem](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/383738/v9-icons-da-ribbon-n%C3%A3o-aparecem)
- [Imprimir documentos de venda na V10](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/381793/imprimir-documentos-de-venda-na-v10)

Comment: Se as perguntas não forem sobre configuração disto mas sobre a linguagem de programação usada para executar algo nele e for realmente um problema nisto ou em um algoritimo programado, com ou sem tag me parece que as perguntas podem existir, creio que a tag não existir não será empecilho, se as perguntas forem validas realmente. Ou estou enganado? Afinal, realmente estou por fora do assunto.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento na minha opinião a tag ajuda filtrar o conteudo relevante quer para quem responde quer para quem pergunta, necesse sentido ajuda e faz sentido

Comment: Ok, mas as perguntas já podem existir, com ou sem tag, parece que concorda com isto, estou certo? Se entendi então e concordamos nisto, é com estas perguntas que acho que você irá conseguir fazer a diferença para justificar a existência da tag, antes dela existir no sistema prove com conteúdo e não com palavras no META que a tag merece seu espaço e faz sentido existir, se as perguntas forem dentro do esperado pela comunidade o próprio conteúdo delas vai provar isto e então a tag pode **nascer naturalmente** e não artificialmente.

Comment: Ontem eu vi o problema de perto. O que pude perceber que as perguntas são demasiadamente focadas no ERP e não nas linguagens que suportam o ERP, fugindo ao propósito principal do site, o propósito de fornecer ajuda ao máximo de pessoas de forma generalizada. A não ser as pessoas que foram treinadas na infraestrutura do ERP, ninguém consegue responder as questões. Quem consegue responder não participa ativamente da comunidade resultando num microcosmo dentro do ptSO de pessoas que não sabem respondendo para pessoas que não entendem que vai diametralmente contra os princípios dessa comunidade.

Comment: Toda manifestação de opinião é bem vinda, mas entendo que este é um assunto que já foi resolvido, diria que com "quase unanimidade" .

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento Concordo que para a tag existir deve ter conteudo para ela, e isso que estou dizendo. Editei a resposta e coloquei alguns exemplos que acho serem a justificação que dizes

Comment: @SérgioSereno certo, como disse, eu não entendo de primavera e nada relacionado, entendo só de algumas linguagens de programação e um pouco do que a comunidade espera do site, no caso logo a primeira pergunta que abri veio com esta resposta: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/381857/3635 -- vou ser sincero, a resposta é pessima, é um exemplo claro de helpdesk, ele não explicou porque a troca resolveria e não explicou a parte técnica, ele só falou, "tenta isso", ou seja não agregou nada, só deu suporte mesmo.

Comment: Essa aqui foi pior (desculpe, preciso ser sincero, minha avaliação é puramente técnica, estou tentando ser imparcial): https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/383783/3635 -- ele deu um script que ele criou e nada de ensinar o porque das coisas, independente do código estar comentado  esta (que é sua): https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/389399/3635 me parece um quase um "erro de digitação", quero dizer, não está ruim, mas foi basicamente um equivocuo (se entendi), até entendo que a intenção foi apresentar a maneira certa de usar, mas precisava de "documentação/referencias" para agregar ali.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento agradeço a sinceridade, mas sejamos honestos, quantas respostas são dadas aqui como a primeira, uma solução para um problema que me impede de avançar? Sem mais nada. Já na segunda, documentação e referencias para a MS ficaria bem melhor, mas volto à mesma questão, quantas temos assim aqui. Expliquei a falha e dei um código a funcionar.

Comment: @SérgioSereno justamente estes tipos de respostas, seja na sua tag primavera, seja em outras tags que tentamos evitar, não é porque ocorreu de algo escapar de nossas vistas que algo se justifique ou que algo é tolerado ou que algo é bom, só significa que escapou, fazemos o melhor possivel para focar nas explicações técnicas e prover alguma qualidade, mas somos poucos fazendo muito, enquanto temos muitos fazendo pouco ou fazendo errado, não é pq tem gente errada que isso justifica fazer o errado. Quero que acredite em mim, estou tentando ser o mais imparcial possível.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento Concordo que conteúdo ruim deve ser removido, mas também estaremos de acordo que os mais novos necessitam de ser ensinados e que será muito difícil conseguirmos ter post's perfeitos. Se as nossa respostas ajudarem outros a alcançarem os seus objetivos, ultrapassar dificuldades, certamente estaremos a prestar um bom serviço à comunidade.

Comment: @SérgioSereno não é só isso, a questão é que se um assunto dá claros sinais (e foi experimentado) vai trazer um tipo de conteúdo que não é o esperado, então este é o possivel motivo da comunidade evitar a tag, até aonde entendo foi experimentado e não deu resultados positivos. Creio que as demais postagens e meses (não pude acompanhar pois na época tive que me ausentar) [...]

Comment: [...] Se com o tempo as perguntas que surgirem forem realmente dentro de 'programação' e não suporte ou configuração e a qualidade das respostas se tornar boa então você pode voltar a solicitar a tag, mas por enquanto não devemos por o carro na frente dos bois. O trabalho agora deve ser dos membros interessados no assunto melhorar, somos todos usuários, eu atuo em diversas tags e oriento quem está nestas tags ou assuntos (mesmo que sem as tags), se puder participar e orientar e criticar quem estiver fazendo errado então talvez algo melhore.